# Is there a way to find out the current volume level?

Tags: 10.04, sound, settings, preferences

Like the question states.

[image: ubuntu volume control applet]

Is it possible to change any system settings such that when I hover over the volume control applet or slider, the current level is shown in a tooltip (the number)? Or is there at all some place from where I can view this.

Even the sound preferences dialog does not show the actual number, which is strange to say the least.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why the number is important to you. Isn't sound better measured by aural means, rather than an arbitrary number? "How loud is it" "65"

Comment: The "aural means" is what is arbitrary; the number is definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I found to get the volume level is to use the command line program [**alsamixer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer).

In the screenshot below, **65** is the current global volume level.

[image]